# XPath: Get next after following sibling

Tags: html, xpath

In the following HTML code I need to extract  `class="list-item-child-label ng-inserted"` but only in that part where I have `class="fat-checkbox-checked"`

```
<fat-option class="fat-option>
    <fat-pseudo-checkbox class="fat-pseudo-checkbox ></fat-pseudo-checkbox>
    <span class="fat-option-text">
        <div class="justify-content">
            <div class="align-items">
                <fat-checkbox class="fat-checkbox-checked">
                </fat-checkbox>
                <div></div>
                <div class="list-item-child-label"> TEXT AAA </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item-child-label ng-inserted"> TEXT BBB </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</fat-option>
<fat-option class="fat-option>
    <fat-pseudo-checkbox class="fat-pseudo-checkbox ></fat-pseudo-checkbox>
    <span class="fat-option-text">
        <div class="justify-content">
            <div class="align-items">
                <fat-checkbox class="fat-checkbox">
                </fat-checkbox>
                <div></div>
                <div class="list-item-child-label"> TEXT AAA </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item-child-label ng-inserted"> TEXT BBB </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</fat-option>
```

These xpaths that I tried to build:

`'//div[contains(@class, "list-item-child-label ng-inserted")]/ancestor::span//div//fat-checkbox[contains(@class, "mat-checkbox-checked")]'`

`'//span//div//fat-checkbox[contains(@class, "fat-checkbox-checked")]/following-sibling::div[2]'`

`'//span//div//fat-checkbox[contains(@class, "fat-checkbox-checked")]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class, "list-item-child-label ng-inserted")]'`

getting me only `class="list-item-child-label"`

Anyone knows how to build correct xpath to get `class="list-item-child-label ng-inserted"` with `class="fat-checkbox-checked"` without using contains(@text)?

Answer (score 1):

Try below XPath to select required node

```
//div[fat-checkbox[@class="fat-checkbox-checked"]]/following-sibling::div[@class="list-item-child-label ng-inserted"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To locate the element `<div class="list-item-child-label ng-inserted">` followed by the element `<fat-checkbox class="fat-checkbox-checked">` you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//fat-checkbox[@class='fat-checkbox-checked']//following::div[@class='list-item-child-label ng-inserted']
```